# How to group rows containing similar element from a table using MYSQL/ Python / Django?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, python-2.7

I have a table being rendered in my HMTL page. The data comes from a MYSQL query and  being rendered using a loop. Let’s say I have this table:

[image]

I'm able to get these data by models -> views - > html

views:

```
def context(request):
    context = {
        "contents": Something.objects.get_contents()
    }
    return render(request, 'contents.html', context)
```

Notice that the only repeating priority is a type of ‘news.’ I am expecting 4 news to show up and they can share similar priorities. Any other genre should have their own priority. How can I write a query and render them to an html page to have an output like this:

[image]

I appreciate all the help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that with a SQL query, try doing the collection in Python.  Make a defaultdict which lets you collect your contents field into a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
contents_dict = defaultdict(list)
for priority, type, content in Something.objects.get_contents():
    contents_dict[(priority, type)].append(content)
```

Then rebuild into a list of tuples

```
table = [key + (','.join(s),) for key, s in contents_dict.items()]
```

then your view looks like:

```
def context(request):
context = {
    "contents": table
}
return render(request, 'contents.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I have not used collections in the past. Will read some docs and try this out! thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT, something like this:

```
SELECT priority, type, GROUP_CONCAT(content SEPARATOR ', ') FROM table GROUP BY priority, type;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat